# How to implement PayPal recurring payment using PayPal Payflow Hosted pages ? Not using IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I want to implement the recurring paymentusing  the payflow link and paypal hosted pages. But going through the development guides of PayPal i couldn't find any effective solution. Say for payflow link my code will be like this :

```
<form method="POST" action="https://mylinktoPayPalPayflow.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="LOGIN" value="Your LOGIN here">

  <input type="hidden" name="PARTNER" value="Your PARTNER here">

  <input type="hidden" name="DESCRIPTION" value="Order description here">

  <input type="hidden" name="AMOUNT" value="Total transaction AMOUNT here">

  <input type="hidden" name="TYPE" value="Transaction TYPE here">

  <input type="submit" value="Click Here to Purchase">
</form>
```

Here : 
**LOGIN:** The login name that you chose for your Payflow account.

**PARTNER:** The name of your Partner was provided to you by your reseller.

**AMOUNT:** Total amount of the transaction. The value must be greater than 1.00.

**TYPE:** A single letter that identifies the type of transaction (S for sale, A for authorization).

But Transaction type is either Sale or Authorization here.

Is there any way to implement the recurring payment here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use the Payflow link , you will have the two options to create recurring profiles :

1. First complete a one time payment using the hosted checkout pages and then use the transaction id (PNREF) that you get to create the recurring profile . This way you need not pass any credit card information as it will automatically be taken from the PNREF . Something like below :

   **PARTNER[6]=PayPal&VENDOR[13]=XXXXXX&USER[6]=XXXXX&PWD[8]=XXXXX&TRXTYPE=R&ACTION=A&TENDER=C&PROFILEREFERENCE=XXXX&PROFILENAME[38]=XAXXXXXAXXX&START=09182014&TERM=0&PAYPERIOD=MONT&AMT[4]=1.07&ORIGID=ESJPC2894AFC**
2. Once you complete the one time payment , go to the manager.paypal.com and look for that transaction id and in the details of the transaction you will see the button to convert it into recurring profile . This is a manual work

For the hosted checkout pages you can pass TYPE= A or S only .

Comment: In 13 lines you put all of PayPal's 'documentation' to shame. :-)